# How to create an Elasticsearch index without word-splitting?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created my ES index as follows (MongoDB via River) :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
       "db": "testmongo", 
       "collection": "person"
    }, 
    "index": {
       "name": "mongoindex", 
        "type": "my_type" 
    }
}'
```

I have some entries in my MongoDB which look like "**MyString.70**" oder "**Test-133**" and when ES is indexing those entries, it's always splitting them into "**MyString**", "**70**", "**Test**", "**133**".

How can I deactivate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By indexing make use of for example

```
...
"mongodb": { 
   "db": "testmongo", 
   "collection": "person",
   "index": "not_analyzed"
},
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to update my available index with that parameter?